# Spring Webflow, return to main flow from any sub-flow

Tags: spring-webflow

I'm trying to return to my main flow in spring, from any of my subflows just by clicking a button.

when I use `<end-state>` it just goes to the previous flow, which is also a sub-flow in the application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need the appropriate transitions in each subflow-state in the calling flow to do what you want.  The end-state id in your subflow is what will be used as the event id you can transition on in your calling flow.

A subflow can be thought of as a branch of execution.  So when your subflow is finished, control is returned back to the calling flow.  Think of your end-state as a return statement (and the id attribute as the value returned -- you can also set output attributes but that is not important here).

When your subflow terminates, control is returned backed to the calling flow.  The calling flow should define a transition that determines how to handle this event.  The event id you will see is the id of the end-state in your subflow.

So in your subflow if you have the following end-state:

```
<end-state id="back"/>
```

You can then handle this transition in the flow that called the subflow:

```
<subflow-state id="do-some-sub" flow="some-sub">
    < ... input variables, expressions, etc ... />
    <transition on="back" to="some-state"/>
</subflow-state>
```

Note that *some-state* here can also be an end-state.  Your situation sounds like you have a main flow that calls a subflow which in turn calls another subflow.  So you would want *some-state* to be an end-state, which would then be handled by its calling flow (in your case the "main" flow).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by  adding the 'parent' attribute when you define your sub flow like this

```
<flow parent="login" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow  http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

<view-state id="forgotPassword">
        <transition on="backtoLogin" to="login">

        </transition>
```

here i want my subflow to return to the login page on a back button 'click' .

One thing to notice is that in your parent flow.xml u need to specify the absolute path of the view

my parent ie login-flow.xml is given below

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow     http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">


<view-state id="login" view="../login/defaultLogin.xhtml">
```